# ¿Por qué mi UPDATE no se realiza?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches, Estoy teniendo problemas con un código php y mysql, 
[image]

Bueno, la imagen anterior es el resultado de un SELECT de una db que contiene 6 usuarios, y es solamente un input que está dentro de un while

```
<?php
require '../conexion.php';
$usuarios="SELECT * FROM usuarios_lg";
$sqlusaurios=$mysqli->query($usuarios);
?>

<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="" action="post.php" method="post">
  <table>
   <tr>

    <td>calificacion</td>

    </tr>
    <?php while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlusaurios)) {?>
    <tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="calificacion" value="<?= $mostrar['calificacion'] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

  </table>
```

Y lo que yo quiero es que al escribir algo en el cualquiera de los input que aparece, me haga el update sólamente en ese campo, pero no me lo realiza en todos los otros, que deberá ir en el WHERE para que haga como quiero? 
este es el archivo a donde ejecuta el action del form

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../conexion.php';

if ($_POST) {

$calif=$_POST['calificacion'];


$update= "UPDATE usuarios_lg SET  calificacion='$calif' WHERE ID = ID";
if ($mysqli->query($update)){
header("Location:prueba.php");
}
else {
echo "Errormessage: ". $mysqli->error;
}
}

?>
```

---

Gracias por responder juan, el ID lo haría en un campo que tengo como principal en mi base de datos, pero quiero que al modificar un valor sobre uno de los campos en "Calificacion" sólo se modifique uno, y al ponerlo, se van todos, qué valor deveria de poner en WHERE ?

Comment: En que ID harias el update? Ahi no lo pasas como variable solo pusiste ID
WHERE ID = ID

Comment: Ya respondí bro.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/45404)

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el campo que guarda el nombre del alumno? Conociendo su nombre se podría poner al lado de cada `<input>` para que conozcas a quién le estás cambiando la calificación.

Answer (score 0):

En tu where estás igualando ID con una cadena ID lo cual no es correcto porque no es una variable y no le estás pasando un valor como tal cambia el = ID por un = '$tuvariable' donde $tuvariable es la variable que representa a tu ID

Comment: La parte de la consulta `ID = ID` es correcta (aunque no realice el trabajo que espera) ya que se pueden comparar valores de campos, incluido comparar un campo con sí mismo (siempre será cierta esa comparación). Y nunca se debe introducir el valor de una variable directamente en una consulta (el `'$tuvariable'` que propones) para evitar inyección SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo hice, añadí en el form otro input el cual era el ID de la bd y el name que lleva es id, ahora en el post.php hice esto $id=$_POST['id'];

y en el update hice esto WHERE ID = $id y sí, se guarda sólamente de un campo y de los demás no, de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cualquiera del id del 1-5 si modifico la calificación a cualquier valor, se reinicia al que tenía, en cambio el 6 no, si se realiza el update que le hice

Comment: ¿Y dónde está el código? Dediqué un buen rato a redactarte una respuesta con una explicación detallada. Espero que la valores.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

- No distingues los campos `<input>` del formulario para cada usuario.
- La consulta SQL actualiza todos los registros porque la igualdad `ID = ID` se cumple en todos ellos (presuponiendo que exista un campo llamado `ID`).

Para solucionar el primer problema debes usar algún sistema para generar un `<input name="...">` diferente por cada usuario:

```
<?php
require '../conexion.php';
$usuarios = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_lg";
$sqlusaurios = $mysqli->query($usuarios);
?><html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="" action="post.php" method="post">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>id</td>    
    <td>calificacion</td>    
    </tr>
    <?php while ($mostrar = $sqlusaurios->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($mostrar['ID']) ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="calificacion[<?= htmlspecialchars($mostrar['ID']) ?>]"
      value="<?= htmlspecialchars($mostrar['calificacion']) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
```

Fíjate que he creado un campo `<input>` cuyo atributo `name` cambia con la `ID` de cada usuario (suponiendo que su clave primaria sea esa, en mayúsculas).

Es una buena costumbre agregar `htmlspecialchars` a cada cadena que envíes al navegador.

El segundo problema lo resolvemos en la recepción. Tendremos como entrada una matriz de elementos `$_POST['calificacion'][]` con duplas `'ID' => 'calificación'` que podremos iterar para almacenar los datos en la base de datos:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../conexion.php';

if (
  isset($_POST['calificacion']) &&
  is_array($_POST['calificacion'])
) {
  /* Preparamos la consulta con dos parámetros "?" */
  $update = $mysqli->prepare('
    UPDATE
      usuarios_lg
    SET
      calificacion = ?
    WHERE
      ID = ?
  ');
  if ($update === false)) {
    die('Error: ' $mysqli->error);
  }
  /* Iteramos por cada calificación */
  foreach ($_POST['calificacion'] as $id => $calificacion) {
    /* Asignamos dos valores enteros a los "?". Presupongo en "calificacion"
      valores enteros, podrían ser decimales usando 'id' */
    $update->bind_param(
      'ii',
      $id,
      $calificacion
    );
    /* Ejecutamos la actualización con los datos proporcionados */
    $update->execute();
  }
  header("Location: prueba.php");
?>
```

Comment: Ya te respondí _bro_.

Answer (score 0):

Oscar García, gracias por tratar de ayudarme, copié el codigo que pusiste anteriormente y lo que obtuve fue lo siguiente;
Si yo escribo en el campo de calificaciones del id 2 el número 5, entonces lo que pasa es que el campo de calificaciones con el id 5 , obtiene el número de id en donde escribí anteriormente, lo explicaré abajo.
Si yo escribo por ejemplo, en el id 2 , el número 6;

id -- Calificaciones
1 ---  0
2 ---  6
3 ---  0
4 ---  0
5 ---  0
6 ---  0

Entonces, el valor que escribí se obtiene como id y se hace el update sobre ese, pero con el valor de id, así.

id - Calificaciones
1 ---  0
2 ---  0
3 ---  0
4 ---  0
5 ---  0
6 ---  2
Ahora ya se pueden modificar todos, el problema es que estan confundidos, qué se puede hacer aquí? y si podrías dejar algun contacto y borrarlo en cuanto respondas para explicarte detalladamente?

Comment: Por favor, no uses respuestas como sustituto de un comentario. Mira lo que debes hacer [cuando alguien te responde (enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). También tienes que tener en cuenta [cómo redactar una buena respuesta (enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Stackoverflow no es un foro en el que se mantienen conversaciones en base a respuestas ni se guarda el orden de ellas, si no que éstas se ordenan según la relevancia y valoración de los usuarios.

Comment: Estaré encantado de ayudarte en la siguiente pregunta que plantees, pero si no lees y cumples las normas de la comunidad y valoras las respuestas y ayuda que te ofrecen es muy probable que no se respondan tus próximas preguntas.

Comment: Ok, no lo volveré a hacer, pero en verdad necesito de su ayuda, necesito entregar este proyecto el día de mañana y me estoy volviendo locoooo.